# Ionic app run function on second tap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a menu in my ionic app that has the following behaviour.

1. Tap once to show the description for that menu item.
2. Tap again to navigate to that page or run the specified function.

I did have my whole menu hardcoded in the template however figure it would be nicer to have an object with the menu items in. This brings me to my main stumbling block of how can I have a function contained within an object.

OR

Am I tackling this completely the wrong way, in which case your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Example code is:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.menuItems = [{
      "title": "Create a Programe",
      "icon": "ion-compose",
    "description" : "Search and add exercises to your prgoramme before sending to your patient"
/*      "action": "openCreateFullProgrammeModal()"
      "action": $state.go('app/clients')
      "action": $state.go('app/programmes')*/
    }, {
      "title": "My Clients",
      "icon": "ion-android-people",
      "description" : "view all your clients"
/*      "action": "openCreateFullProgrammeModal()"
      "action": $state.go('app/clients')
      "action": $state.go('app/programmes')*/
    }, {
      "title": "Programmes",
      "icon": "ion-clipboard",
      "description" : "Browse your programe library"
/*      "action": "openCreateFullProgrammeModal()"
      "action": $state.go('app/clients')
      "action": $state.go('app/programmes')*/
    }

  ]

});
```

Template:

```
  <div class="descriptionArea">
      <p>testing</p>

    </div>
    <div class="home-bottom">
      <div ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
        <ion-item class="item-icon-left home-links" href="#" ng-click="openCreateFullProgrammeModal()">
          <i ng-class="item.icon" class="icon home-link-icon"></i> {{item.title}}
          <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-forward home-icon-right"></i>
        </ion-item>
      </div>

    </div>
```

A codepen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/vOqwvx?editors=101)

Many thanks.

EDIT

[This](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/vOqwvx?editors=101) is what I did in the end...

Answer (score 1):

First your approach in hardcoding the menu is not practical you should use `ng-repeat` for that.

Second here is a codepen for the tapping functionality, I did an example to show you how to make it and you can extend it and implement the go functionality.

[here is the codepin](http://codepen.io/midoalone/pen/xGooEE?editors=101)

Comment: But if I am using `ng-repeat` how do I include the relevant function in my object data?

Comment: You should make just one receiver and specify a flag for each menu item for example `{menu_id: 'program'}` and use it as a method param and you can then use if condition to detect which menu item was tapped.

Comment: for ng-repeat you can just put a ng-click on the repeated items and then say ng-click="myFunction($index)" then on the back side just pass in the index so myFunction(index){console.log($scope.mydata[index])}